# How to find normal to sphere?

Tags: geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus

A subset $S$ of  $\mathbb R^n$ is called a hypersurface of class $C^k (1\leq k \leq \infty)$ if for
every $x_0\in S$ there is an open set $V\subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $x_0$ and a real-valued
function  $\phi \in C^k(V)$ such that  $\nabla  \phi$ is nonvanishing on $S\cap V$ and $S\cap V = \{ x\in V: \phi(x)=0 \}.$

With $S, V, \phi$ as above, the vector $\nabla \phi(x)$ is perpendicular to $S$ at $x$
for every $x\in S\cap V.$

We shall always suppose that $S$ is oriented, that
is, that we have made a choice of unit vector $v(x)$ for each $x\in S$, varying
continuously with $x$ which is perpendicular to $S$ at $x.$

$v(x)$ will be called
the normal to $S$ at $x.$

Put $A:= \{x\in \mathbb R^n: |x|=r \}  (r>0).$

> Question: Is $A$
>   hypersurface of class $C^1$? What is $\phi $ for $A$
>   ? How to find the normal $v(x)$ to $A$ at $x\in A$? (I think,for each $x\in A,$ the $v(x)\subset \mathbb R^n$, please correct me if I am wrong..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is indeed a smooth hypersurface. A possible $\phi$ would be
$$\phi(x)=|x|^2-r^2.$$
Then $\phi$ is smooth and $\nabla \phi=2x$. Therefore a possible unit normal would be
$$v(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}=\frac{x}{r}.$$